# Avi networks - Controller user accounts with private keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, avi, devops

We are just beginning to use Avi in AWS and I am setting up the controller instance. 
As I am adding users to the controller instance I would like for users that log in to the instance via shell do so with private/public keypair authentication.

I created a user and added their public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys , I also added a NOPASSWD entry, but it seems to still be prompting for a password. Can I log in to the GUI with a password but restrict shell access to keypair only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avi Controller ssh expects the key for each user to be in a separate file at /etc/ssh/authorized_keys_username

The SSH config at /etc/ssh/sshd_config sets the path to the authorized keys:
**AuthorizedKeysFile  /etc/ssh/authorized_keys_%u**

You can restrict the user to use keys for shell access by changing /etc/ssh/sshd_config file; but these changes will get overwritten every time you upgrade to a new version.

There is a match option that can disable any users password-based shell access in /etc/ssh/sshd_config


**Match User sysadmin,root,aviseuser,avictlruser,testuser
    PasswordAuthentication no**